# If $9\cdot M \cdot N = \overline{abcde}$, then find all pairs (M, N)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question goes follow

> M is a two-digit natural number $\overline{ab}$ while N is a three-digit natural number $\overline{cde}$. If $9\cdot M \cdot N = \overline{abcde}$, then find all pairs (M, N) that satisfy.

All can i conclude is that $9MN=1000M+N$. It means that $M+N\equiv0 $ $(\mod 9)$ I am stuck on there. Please share me your idea.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: i have done so many manipulation and got nothing. Please, any idea will be apreciated 

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange your equation to get
$$
(9M-1)N=1000M.
$$
$9M-1$ is coprime with $M$ so for integer solutions you have to have $(9M-1)|1000$. A numerical search from 10 to 99 yields only $M=14$, since $9\times14-1=125|1000$ and $N=1000M/125=112$. (There might be a way to skip the numerical search, but I couldn't think of one.)

Comment: Wow, you must be really good at number theory. thank you very much, i learned a lot ☺️

Comment: If I was good at number theory I would be able to think of a way to show that only 14 is a solution without using a computer to search.

Comment: How bout  list all possible values of 9M-1 which are positive factor of 1000. Then solve for M. Here, we need only evaluate 16 cases. Once again, thanks for sharing your idea 

Comment: @AbuNussa We can do even better than that.  Since 2 and 5 are inverse mod 9, and we are looking for a factor congruent to -1, we can limit our search to factors having only 2s or only 5s (as it is easy to find all the other solutions from that).  Additionally, since M>9, 9M-1>88, which immediately rules out everything except 125.  If 9M-1=125, M=14.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed. That's a very good idea. how did you come up with this idea?

Comment: @AbuNussa Since things of the form $9M-1$ are exactly the things congruent to $-1 \pmod 9$ and the divisors of a number can all be described using the prime factorization, I figured I would look at the prime factorization mod 9.  If the two prime factors hadn't had such a nice relationship with each other, I would have either abandoned that approach or represented them as powers (mod 9) of a generator of the group of units.  However, I hit on a good observation that made things especially nice.